# ForEach doesn't update main array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add some additional values to each item of an array. So I have an array with objects and they have: x, y and z fields. I then want to add additional items to each object in the array based on a http.get call's response.

Main array is: **posts**

See code below:

```
router.get('/api/posts', function(req, res){

    postModel.find({})
        .limit(10)
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
            var options = {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                path: '/user?id=12345678',
                method: 'GET'
            };
            if(posts){
                posts.forEach(function(post) {

                    var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
                        var bodyChunks = [];
                        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                            bodyChunks.push(chunk);
                        }).on('end', function() {
                            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
                            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
                            post.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;
                            post.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic;
                        });
                    });      
                });
            res.json({
                posts       :   posts
            });
            } else {
                res.send('Post does not exist');
            }
        });
});
```

At the time of the **post.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic** - the **profilePic** variable is there but when I get a response from node via **res.json**, the additional values are not.

What am I missing here? I use this approach with my Angular frontend all the time without an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Try one thing: assign `post` to some variable `var temp = post`. Then  add `fullname` and `profilePic` to that variable `temp.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;` and `post.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic`. Now return `temp`  instead of `posts`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This approach will work but surely there is a more native way right? I will have to push to the array where most of the data is already there which will lead to a huge overhead on memory (the real data is vast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incredibly common problem, you are treating asynchronous code as if it were synchronous. `http.get` does not complete immediately, nor does it block the code from continuing on, therefore `res.json` is called before your requests complete. There are a ton of ways to fix this, I'll post my favorite - [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
// use map instead of forEach to transform your array
// of posts into an array of promises
var postPromises = posts.map(function(post) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
        var bodyChunks = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            bodyChunks.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', function() {
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
            post.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;
            post.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic;
            // resolve the promise with the updated post
            resolve(post);
        });
    });
  });
});

// once all requests complete, send the data
Promise.all(postPromises).then(function(posts) {
  res.json({
    posts: posts
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah one of these ones again! I hate how I always get caught up in them. Thanks a lo Rob. This worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Node work according to callbacks. You callbacks not completed in the forEach Loop and you are giving response to user. This is the issue.

Write code for that I can suggest solution.

```
router.get('/api/posts', function(req, res){

    postModel.find({})
        .limit(10)
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
            var options = {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                path: '/user?id=12345678',
                method: 'GET'
            };
            if(posts){
                var EventEmitter = require('events');
                var HttpEvent = new EventEmitter();
                let counts = 0;
                let length = posts.length;

                posts.forEach(function(post) {

                    var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
                        var bodyChunks = [];
                        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                            bodyChunks.push(chunk);
                        }).on('end', function() {
                            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
                            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
                            posts.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;
                            posts.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic;
                            HttpEvent.emit('done');
                        });
                    });      
                });

                HttpEvent.on('done',()=>{
                    counts += 1;
                    if(counts == length){
                         res.json({
                            posts       :   posts
                        });
                    }
                })

            } else {
                res.send('Post does not exist');
            }
        });
});
```

One more wrong thing you are doing is

```
 post.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;
 post.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic;
```

It should be

```
 posts.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;
 posts.profilePic = parsedBody.user.profilePic;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just gave it a go but it didn't work. The data returned still doesn't have the values. Also for the **post.fullname = parsedBody.user.fullname;** - it is named in that way as it's part of the loop. I pass **post** in the forEach